# Send email attachment

Tags: windows, vbscript

I'm new to vbs script but in this code I cant get the  attachment to be sent.  it sends the email but no attachment
Can anyone help

```
DIM fso
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
On Error Resume Next
fso.CopyFile "C:\ASoft32\*.*", "E:\ASoft32\"
'Wscript.Echo "File copy complete."
strSMTPFrom = "jbmotors@hotmail.com"
strSMTPTo = "iain@252.co.uk"
strSMTPRelay = "smtp.live.com"
strTextBody = "Backup done vbs"
strSubject = "VBS ALERT"
strAddAttachment "(C:\ASoft32\Hamer.ftm)"
Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTPRelay
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
oMessage.Subject = strSubject
oMessage.From = strSMTPFrom
oMessage.To = strSMTPTo
oMessage.TextBody = strTextBody
oMessage.AddAttachment  strADDAttachment
oMessage.Send
'Wscript.Echo "Email sent."
Const TIMEOUT = 2
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Popup "Email sent" , TIMEOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

`strAddAttachment "(C:\ASoft32\Hamer.ftm)"` in your code won't work.

Try:

`strAddAttachment = "C:\ASoft32\Hamer.ftm"`

Assuming that the file exists in this location, that should work.

Comment: I've tried that and no success but if i change the SMTP.live.com to my  virgin SMTP server the email goes through with an empty attachment.

Comment: I've tried that and no success but if i change the SMTP.live.com to my  virgin SMTP server the email goes through with an empty attachment. the script is going to run on a PC that has no accounts in Outlook, these is the email attachment it sends  "Untitled Attachment 00212.dat (55B)